# Ensure that Oracle runs a group of subqueries / CTEs remotely before joining data from a local table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance, dblink

We have some reasonably complex queries that depend on tables on a remote db accessed via dblink.
The main data comes from the remote db and the local tables are used to translate the central system's transaction ids into the local system's, add extra attributes and filter on them.

```
SELECT rmote.*, 
       locl.local_id
  FROM some_local_table locl
  JOIN (-- REMOTE: This entire block only uses tables from the remote db
        WITH
          part1 as (SELECT ...
                      FROM r.table1
                      JOIN r.table2 ON (...)),
          part2 as ( etc. )
        SELECT ...
       )
       rmote ON (rmote.central_id = locl.central_id)    
 WHERE locl.propx IN (...)
```

The queries are very slow if the execution plan involves accessing the remote tables individually (*r.table1* and *r.table2* in the dummy code above).
Is it possible to to run the entire "remote" block on the remote server and send the results back as a temporary table to be joined, locally, to the local table(s)?

Comment: Some suggestions: Materialized View connected to remote data refreshed before using, pipeline function on remote site, global temporary table on remote site filled by procedure called before to use the data.

Comment: Have you tried the [DRIVING_SITE hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABEGIJC)?  In theory it's supposed to be able to do this, although in practice I have a hard time getting the hint to work.  Creating a view on the remote system may also help.